# StructureMap: register as implemented interfaces like in AutoFac

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac, structuremap

Until recently I used AutoFac which had the method `AsImplementedInterfaces()`
which does

> Register the type as providing all of its public interfaces as services (excluding IDisposable).

that means (for example a service) I have some base interface and an interface for every concerte service-class

See the simple code below:

```
public interface IService {}

public interface IMyService: IService 
{
    string Hello();
}

public class MyService: IMyService
{
    public string Hello()
    {
        return "Hallo";
    }
}

// just a dummy class to which IMyService should be injected 
// (at least that's how I'd do it with AutoFac.
public class MyClass
{
   public MyClass(IMyService myService) { }
}
```

Basically I want to inject my service's interface (so to speak) and not the concrete service.

Now I have to use StructureMap but I struggle to find what I need.
There is `AddAllTypesOf<T>` but this would register the concrete type.

is this even possible with StructureMap and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, I found the answer(s)

1.
first you could use

```
public class TestRegistry : Registry
{
    public TestRegistry()
    {
        Scan(x =>
        {
            x.TheCallingAssembly();
            x.RegisterConcreteTypesAgainstTheFirstInterface();
        });
    }
}
```

this will register every concrete class against the first interface which might be too broad.

2.
if so you can use the following code I adapted from http://structuremap.github.io/registration/auto-registration-and-conventions/.

I had to change `Each()` to `foreach` because of compilation errors and made the whole class generic.

```
public class AllInterfacesConvention<T> : IRegistrationConvention
{
    public void ScanTypes(TypeSet types, Registry registry)
    {
        // Only work on concrete types
        foreach (var type in types.FindTypes(TypeClassification.Concretes | TypeClassification.Closed).Where(x => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(x)))
        {
            if(type == typeof(NotInheritedClass))
            {
                continue;
            }

            // Register against all the interfaces implemented
            // by this concrete class
            foreach (var @interface in type.GetInterfaces())
            {
                registry.For(@interface).Use(type);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if you take the code sample from the link every concrete type would be included. With my changes only concerte classes which inherit from `T` will be included.

in your registry you would use it like that

```
public class TestRegistry : Registry
{
    public TestRegistry()
    {
        Scan(x =>
        {
           x.TheCallingAssembly();
           x.Convention<AllInterfacesConvention<YOUR_BASE_INTERFACE>>();
        });
    }
}
```

Be aware the structuremap's `GetInstance` will always resolve concrete classes no matter if you previously registered them. 
See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4807950/885338